# Geocode sync with GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to put `Info Window` on markers in a Google Map. I make an Ajax query to get a list of markers to draw in my map and I have a sync problem because the:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': citta}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {}
```

Is asynchronous so if I call it inside a loop I get the wrong results. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to do a synchronous call?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the following answer [Google Maps API Geocode Synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310153/google-maps-api-geocode-synchronously). The answer is no.