# How Do I store the value of Lat and Lon using google.maps.Geocoder() in a array?

Tags: javascript, geocoding

I am using google maps Geocoder to track coordinates of cities. I am not able to store the coordinates in an array. I am getting empty array. The coordinates exist inside the "if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)" but it is empty outside the  loop.

```
function getcorrdinates(address){ 
    var result = "";
    var arr = [];
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address[i] }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                result = results[0].geometry.location;
                arr.push(result);
                alert ("Print Array inside the loop "+arr);//has value

            }
            else 
            {                                        
                        alert(" failed");

            }

        });
    }
   alert ("Print Array outside For loop "+arr); //is empty
return arr; 
}
```

So, here "alert "("Print Array inside the loop "+arr)" has values but when it is outside the loop it is empty and outside the loop gets executed first than the inside the loop. How can I store the values in a array so that I can use it for another function.

I am new to JavaScript, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the asynchronicity of the geocode method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310153/google-maps-api-geocode-synchronously

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540979/geocode-sync-with-googlemaps